# Flutter Api not working with web and release apk but working in debugmide

Tags: flutter, api, rest, flutter-web

Why Rest Api Not Working In Flutter Web and build apk only working(fetching info) in debug mode

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you have added internet permission in android manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Yeah thanks but not yet working for web?

Comment: Does it show any error in web?

Comment: no it's just getting buffered all the time ... But in vain i found that the permissions needs to be changed from the server side..

Comment: Open inspect elements and check. You may also face cors error